# Blacklist post build event gacutil in azure pipeline

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, pipeline, post-build-event

Is there a way in Azure pipeline to blacklist a certain post build event like gacutil? I want the pipeline to fail when the Build solution task sees "e.g. :\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0....." ?

Comment: this is quite custom requirement. you can add a powershell task for the same in the pipeline.

Comment: Yeah, i will also say that a PS task will fix that problem. Thanks !!